# Eclipse freshly installed from official repo : JVM terminated, Exit code=1

Tags: arch-linux, eclipse

I just installed eclipse from the official arch repo and have this error

```
JVM terminated, Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
...
```

I need it for the C debugger, any idea how to fix this ?

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.7) (Arch Linux build 7.u111_2.6.7-1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.111-b01, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Arch linux, you have to first install jdk8-openjdk:

```
pacman -S jdk8-openjdk
```

and then [set the default java version](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/java#Change_default_Java_environment) to java 8:

```
archlinux-java set java-8-openjdk/jre
```

Answer (score 2):

Java version 1.8 is needed to run the latest Eclipse, it even says so in the error message you posted: `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8`. You have version 1.7. Is there some reason why you can't upgrade to OpenJDK 8?

Comment: No I just thought everything was taken care of by the dependency system and I had no clue what part of the java system had to be changed, I know nothing about java haha